# Generic embedding solution

Tags: javascript, feed

I want to start embedding media content on instaright.com in Twitter, Friendfeed, Facebook like manner, but can't come up with any satisfying solution. Is there any generic solution regarding this issue or it has to be per site implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) which at least used to seem like a nicely growing way of embedding various external content on your site... Dunno if it has really been picking on that much lately, but I think it's still a decent idea and works for a bunch of sites too.